# How do I improve myself and go beyond what I have learned ?. I am willing to dedicate a lot of time!

Tags: education, learning, online-resources

Hello good people of Mathematics!

I am a grade 10 student in Canada who would like to better improve himself. I have posted a question on here that was pretty simple before.

Nonetheless, I am a passionate student in a bit of a dilemma. I have a lot of pressure (Indian Dad lol) which is forcing me to get very high marks in mathematical subjects. I am trying my best to learn what is in my curriculum for North American Grade 10. I would also like to go above that and learn more things about math that have always interested me.

A bit about me for the people that would like to know. I am an intermediate programmer in High School. The difficult part is that I tend to use programmer logic (something like a lot of loops to solve for an exponent) rather than mathematical logic (a simple algorithm to do an exponent).

I am known as the smart guy of the class and have the highest average (not very high thanks to my difficult marker of a teacher). I am very willing to learn and dedicate a lot of time. I understand everything from Grade 9 to below.

To clear up my question, what are some resources to help me better my learning? Or what can I do to learn new topics, and where do I start?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Math is pretty big.  It's kind of hard to give general advice - it's like asking "where in the world should I visit?"  It depends on your interests.  You might look to see if there is a local "math circle" or similar program for advanced students.

Comment: Thanks! I actually just joined our school’s math contest prep club. I get what you are pointing towards, but I’m looking more for online resources as I’m guessing none of my club mates would be interested in helping me (they’re probably more interested in prepping for their own grade level). I guess what I’m going towards is that I want to improve by learning stuff by myself/online. Any resources, or a place to start would help!

Comment: I never did contest-style math myself, so I can't advise on that.  I'd ask your teachers (or see if others chime in here.)

Comment: Yeah, a contest wasn’t the best choice, but it’s the closest thing our school has to a “math” club. Nonetheless, thanks for your input! I haven’t asked my teachers yet because she wants to focus her time on helping the lower end of students in terms of understanding the topics.

Comment: Maybe try reading The Art of Problem Solving volumes 1 and 2. Or else find other books you like. And remember, "Don't just read it -- fight it!" Be sure to learn how to derive everything from scratch, so you aren't just taking things on faith.